# notification to approve edit on my questions

Tags: bug

This is the second or third question where I see the same behaviour and I'd like to understand if it is a bug or not.

- I post a question on SO;
- Someone edit my question;
- I receive a    notification to approve the edit on my question or to
  improve it;
- I improve the edit and SO will tell me that I need to have at
  least 2k rep to perform this action 
  OR
- I accept the edit and the result is the same.

Why can I see the edit queue on my questions if I cannot act on it?

Comment: If you choose `Improve` again is it the same? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95520/allow-improve-for-tag-wiki-edit-suggestions/96233#96233